# Change value in <xsl:value-of select="image"/>

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to change an image path.

The code to display the image is:
`<xsl:value-of select="image"/>`

the image path it takes from the feed is:

```
https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/1/7/image.jpg
```

what i would like is:

```
https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/thumbnail/folder/1/7/image.jpg
```

i tried the following:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>

    <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">

        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="image"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="product[position() = 1]">


    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="'https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'product/'" />
    <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'product/thumbnail/folder/'"/>

    </xsl:call-template>

   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is:

```
https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/thumbnail/folder/https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/image.jpg
```

not getting a real error message, it is just showing twice the http part

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't this be a lot simpler? For example, consider:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <product>
        <image>https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/1/7/image.jpg</image>
    </product>
    <product>
        <image>https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/2/56/image.jpg</image>
    </product>
    <product>
        <image>https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/3/123/image.jpg</image>
    </product>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <images>
        <xsl:for-each select="product">
            <image>
                <xsl:text>https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/thumbnail/folder/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(image, 'https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/')" />
            </image>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </images>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<images>
  <image>https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/thumbnail/folder/1/7/image.jpg</image>
  <image>https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/thumbnail/folder/2/56/image.jpg</image>
  <image>https://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/thumbnail/folder/3/123/image.jpg</image>
</images>
```